# Modify The Circuit

Tags: power-electronics, ac-dc, step-down

[image: DC Step down using VIPER16]

**EDIT**: I want to produce +12 Volts as well as -12 volts output. It would be very helpful if someone can suggest changes in component values keeping the structure same. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the voltage at pin 3 of U2?  That is a 5 Volt linear regulator.  Pin 3 is its input.  If thatvis at around 14Volts or more, then you can replace the 7805 with a 7812.  If not, you need to mention just what exactly U1 is.  Only then can someone help you modify its circuit to provide enough voltage to drive a 12V linear regulator.

Comment: More simply:  What exactly is U1?

Comment: @JRE It's 15V. Notice D6. I would bump the zener V up a volt or so.

Comment: Ok.  U1 is a Viper16.  That didn't look like a part number.

Comment: The circuit provides 15V and 5 V.  You should be able to use a 7812 in place of the 7805. That will provide 12V and 15V on J2.

Comment: @JRE Sorry but you are wrong. U1 generates 12V and not 15V. The 15V zener is for protection. See the application note in my answer.

Comment: @MikeWaters you are wrong, too. No 15V but 12V.

Answer (score 7):

If you study closely the [application note](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/38/6a/ed/ce/63/7f/46/f7/CD00222186.pdf/files/CD00222186.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00222186.pdf), where I suppose you found this schematic, it says clearly that this circuit outputs 12V on J2.1 (pin 1 of J2). See also Figure 1 on its first page. So, you have the solution already there. No modifications are necessary.

This means the U1 generates directly 12V at its output. The application note, last paragraph on page 10, also says that if you want to modify the U1 circuit so that 5V is directly generated without using U2, you can just change R3 to 4.7 kOhm.

Also, the voltage \$V_{o}\$ at the output of VIPer16 can be calculated as following: \$V_{FB}\$ is 3.3V (as the datasheet of the converter says), so \$V_{o}\$ through the voltage divider formed by R3 and R4 should give 3.3V. Thus \$V_{o} \cdot \frac{R4}{R3+R4} = 3.3V \$ and plugging in the numbers we get \$V_{o} = 3.3V \cdot \frac{R3+R4}{R4} = 12V \$. By changing the value of either of the two resistors you get the \$V_{o}\$ that you want to achieve.

Comment: glad you provided the source, should we start to insist that people posting should provide the sources for material they use?

Comment: Yes, I guess we should. I think it's quite important. Unless, of course, there is no source.

Comment: @SolarMike is that not currently considered a requirement on this site? D: Yes, I would definitely recommend insisting people provide sources if they have them.

Answer (score 0):

Tweak R4. The voltage between it and R3 is 3.3V (because closed loop) so just calculate it. You will then keep the 5V output and change 15V to 12V.

Answer (score 0):

This circuit cannot be modified to produce a negative output.  Or, not without a significant re-design.  Note that this answer is independent of the output current you need, even though you are keeping that little detail a secret.